# Move zeroes to the end of array

Tags: erlang

For the problem of moving zeroes to the back of the array as detailed [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/move-zeroes-end-array/). I did it like below in Erlang. I just think my way is very basic and probably there is a more elegant way to do it using recursion?

```
-module(move_zeroes).
-compile([export_all, debug_info]).

%% This is solving this problem: 

%% API exports
-export([]).

move_zeroes(L) ->
    moving_zeroes(L, []).

moving_zeroes(L, _) ->
    Zeroes = lists:filter(fun(X) -> X == 0 end, L),
    Non = lists:filter(fun(X) -> X /= 0 end, L),
    Non ++ Zeroes.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem that's well suited to elementwise aggregation. Consider the following:

```
move_zeroes (L) ->
    case L of
       [0 | T] -> move_zeroes(T) ++ [0];
       [El | T] -> [El] ++ move_zeroes(T);
       _Else -> L
    end.
```

I am only blindly guessing at the syntax here, but this should clarify how one would write this without using `lists:filter` twice. It additionally avoids the helper function you created there, which seems to not serve a purpose ...

Comment: It must be `[0]` instead `0` because you append list to list here.

Comment: Every time you see a zero, you append two lists together which requires a complete traversal of the first list in order to prepend its elements. I believe this makes your algorithm O(n^2), which doesn't meet the complexity requirement of the problem. Even though the poster's solution iterates through each list twice, its complexity is still O(n).